# How to ignore the first line of data when processing CSV data?

Tags: python, csv

I am asking Python to print the minimum number from a column of CSV data, but the top row is the column number, and I don't want Python to take the top row into account. How can I make sure Python ignores the first line?

This is the code so far:

```
import csv

with open('all16.csv', 'rb') as inf:
    incsv = csv.reader(inf)
    column = 1                
    datatype = float          
    data = (datatype(column) for row in incsv)   
    least_value = min(data)

print least_value
```

Could you also explain what you are doing, not just give the code? I am very very new to Python and would like to make sure I understand everything.

Comment: Are you aware that you're just creating a generator that returns a `1.0` for each line in your file and then taking the minimum, which is going to be `1.0`?

Comment: @Wooble Technically, it's a big generator of `1.0`. :)

Comment: @Wooble good catch - ...`datatype(row[column]`... is what I guess the OP is trying to achieve though

Comment: i had someone write up that code for me and didnt catch that, so thanks haha!

Answer (score 120, accepted):

You could use an instance of the `csv` module's [**`Sniffer`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Sniffer) class to deduce the format of a CSV file and detect whether a header row is present along with the built-in `next()` function to skip over the first row only when necessary:

```
import csv

with open('all16.csv', 'r', newline='') as file:
    has_header = csv.Sniffer().has_header(file.read(1024))
    file.seek(0)  # Rewind.
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    if has_header:
        next(reader)  # Skip header row.
    column = 1
    datatype = float
    data = (datatype(row[column]) for row in reader)
    least_value = min(data)

print(least_value)
```

Since `datatype` and `column` are hardcoded in your example, it would be slightly faster to process the `row` like this:

```
    data = (float(row[1]) for row in reader)
```

**Note:** the code above is for Python 3.x. For Python 2.x use the following line to open the file instead of what is shown:

```
with open('all16.csv', 'rb') as file:
```

Comment: Instead of `has_header(file.read(1024))`, does it make sense to write `has_header(file.readline())` ?  I see that a lot, but I don't understand how `has_reader()` could detect whether or not there's a header from a single line of the CSV file...

Comment: @Anto: The code in my answer is based on the "example for Sniffer use" in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Sniffer), so I assume it's the prescribed way to do it. I agree that doing it on the basis of one line of data doesn't seem like it would always be enough data to make such a determination—but I have no idea since _how_ the `Sniffer` works isn't described. FWIW I've **never** seen `has_header(file.readline())` being used and even if it worked most of time, I would be highly suspicious of the approach for the reasons stated.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  Nevertheless it seems that using `file.read(1024)` [generates errors in python's csv lib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35757505/1030960): . See also [here](https://github.com/xesscorp/KiField/issues/17#issuecomment-262871084) for instance.

Comment: @Anto: I've never encountered such an error—1024 bytes is not a lot of memory after all—nor has it been a problem for many other folks based on the up-votes this answer has received (as well as the thousands of of people who have read and followed the documentation). For those reasons I strongly suspect something else is causing your issue.

Comment: I ran into this exact same error as soon as I switched from `readline()` to `read(1024)`.  So far I've only managed to find people who have switched to readline to solve the csv.dialect issue.

Comment: @Anto: In that case I suggest you post your own question about why this is happening. Be sure to include the least amount of code that, when run, will reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: How do I skip the first row if I want to use `csv.DictReader` instead of `csv.reader`? In my case the CSV starts with a row that explains to humans reading the sheet what each column means.

Comment: @Boris: If the file has more than one row/line at the beginning with the fieldnames in it — i.e. the optional so-called "header" row — then it's not in a valid CSV format. About the only thing I can think of is that you may be able to call `next(file)` right after opening it to skip over that if you know for certain it will be there. You will also need to rewind the file back to that point *plus* any standard normal header that was detected by the `csv.Sniffer` before passing it to `csv.reader`.

Answer (score 90):

To skip the first line just call:

```
next(inf)
```

Files in Python are iterators over lines.

Comment: Nice summary of files in Python

Comment: can you give a link where you found this? any link to the next() documentation where it mentions the parameters for the next function.

Comment: @bluetail https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next

Comment: If one of the values in the first row can contain a newline `\n` character, this won't work.

Comment: @user3064538: to skip a parsed csv row, call next on the csv reader itself: `next(incsv)`

Answer (score 43):

Borrowed from [python cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00DQV4GGY), 
A more concise template code might look like this:

```
import csv
with open('stocks.csv') as f:
    f_csv = csv.reader(f) 
    headers = next(f_csv) 
    for row in f_csv:
        # Process row ...
```

Answer (score 25):

In a similar use case I had to skip annoying lines before the line with my actual column names. This solution worked nicely. Read the file first, then pass the list to `csv.DictReader`.

```
with open('all16.csv') as tmp:
    # Skip first line (if any)
    next(tmp, None)

    # {line_num: row}
    data = dict(enumerate(csv.DictReader(tmp)))
```

Comment: Thanks Veedrac. Happy to learn here, can you suggest edits that would solve the problems you cite? My solution gets the job done, but it looks like it could be further improved?

Comment: I gave you an edit that replaces the code with something that should be identical (untested). Feel free to revert if it's not in line with what you mean. I'm still not sure why you're making the `data` dictionary, nor does this answer really add anything over the accepted one.

Comment: Thanks Veedrac! That looks very efficient indeed. I posted my answer because the accepted one was not working for me (can't remember the reason now). What would be the problem with defining data = dict() and then immediately filling it (as compared to your suggestion)?

Comment: It's not *wrong* to do `data = dict()` and fill it in, but it's inefficient and not idiomatic. Plus, one should use dict literals (`{}`) and `enumerate` even then.

Comment: FWIW, you should reply to my posts with `@Veedrac` if you want to be sure I'm notified, although Stack Overflow seems to be able to guess from the username along. (I don't write `@Maarten` because the answerer will be notified by default.)

Comment: If one of the values in the first row can contain a newline `\n` character, this won't work.

Answer (score 19):

You would normally use `next(incsv)` which advances the iterator one row, so you skip the header. The other (say you wanted to skip 30 rows) would be:

```
from itertools import islice
for row in islice(incsv, 30, None):
    # process
```

Answer (score 8):

use csv.DictReader instead of csv.Reader.
If the fieldnames parameter is omitted, the values in the first row of the csvfile will be used as field names. you would then be able to access field values using row["1"] etc

Answer (score 5):

**Python 2.x**

[**`csvreader.next()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#reader-objects)

> Return the next row of the reader’s iterable object as a list, parsed
> according to the current dialect.

```
csv_data = csv.reader(open('sample.csv'))
csv_data.next() # skip first row
for row in csv_data:
    print(row) # should print second row
```

---

**Python 3.x**

[**`csvreader.__next__()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#reader-objects)

> Return the next row of the reader’s iterable object as a list (if the
> object was returned from reader()) or a dict (if it is a DictReader
> instance), parsed according to the current dialect. Usually you should
> call this as next(reader).

```
csv_data = csv.reader(open('sample.csv'))
csv_data.__next__() # skip first row
for row in csv_data:
    print(row) # should print second row
```

Comment: Docs say "Usually you should call this as `next(reader)`." https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvreader.__next__

Answer (score 4):

this might be a very old question but with pandas we have a very easy solution

```
import pandas as pd

data=pd.read_csv('all16.csv',skiprows=1)
data['column'].min()
```

with skiprows=1 we can skip the first row then we can find the least value using data['column'].min()

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation for the Python 3 CSV module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Sniffer) provides this example:

```
with open('example.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(1024))
    csvfile.seek(0)
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect)
    # ... process CSV file contents here ...
```

The `Sniffer` will try to auto-detect many things about the CSV file. You need to explicitly call its `has_header()` method to determine whether the file has a header line. If it does, then skip the first row when iterating the CSV rows. You can do it like this:

```
if sniffer.has_header():
    for header_row in reader:
        break
for data_row in reader:
    # do something with the row
```

Answer (score 2):

The new 'pandas' package might be more relevant than 'csv'. The code below will read a CSV file, by default interpreting the first line as the column header and find the minimum across columns.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('all16.csv')
data.min()
```

Comment: and you can write it in one line too: `pd.read_csv('all16.csv').min()`

Comment: It's two lines @Finn - you forgot to include ``import pandas`` - which is where you add a whole lot of work just for reading a csv file. Why not use the ``csv`` standard library for what it's designed for?

Answer (score 2):

Because this is related to something I was doing, I'll share here.

What if we're not sure if there's a header and you also don't feel like importing sniffer and other things?

If your task is basic, such as printing or appending to a list or array, you could just use an if statement:

```
# Let's say there's 4 columns
with open('file.csv') as csvfile:
     csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
# read first line
     first_line = next(csvreader)
# My headers were just text. You can use any suitable conditional here
     if len(first_line) == 4:
          array.append(first_line)
# Now we'll just iterate over everything else as usual:
     for row in csvreader:
          array.append(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, my [mini wrapper library](http://pyexcel.readthedocs.org/en/v0.0.9/index.html) would do the job as well.

```
>>> import pyexcel as pe
>>> data = pe.load('all16.csv', name_columns_by_row=0)
>>> min(data.column[1])
```

Meanwhile, if you know what header column index one is, for example "Column 1", you can do this instead:

```
>>> min(data.column["Column 1"])
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the easiest way to go is to use range.

```
import csv

with open('files/filename.csv') as I:
    reader = csv.reader(I)
    fulllist = list(reader)

# Starting with data skipping header
for item in range(1, len(fulllist)): 
    # Print each row using "item" as the index value
    print (fulllist[item])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would convert csvreader to list, then pop the first element

```
import csv        

with open(fileName, 'r') as csvfile:
        csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        data = list(csvreader)               # Convert to list
        data.pop(0)                          # Removes the first row

        for row in data:
            print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use *tail* to get rid of the unwanted first line:

```
tail -n +2 $INFIL | whatever_script.py
```

Answer (score 0):

just add **[1:]**

example below:

```
data = pd.read_csv("/Users/xyz/Desktop/xyxData/xyz.csv", sep=',', header=None)**[1:]**
```

that works for me in iPython

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.X

Handles UTF8 BOM + HEADER

It was quite frustrating that the `csv` module could not easily get the header, there is also a bug with the UTF-8 BOM (first char in file).
This works for me using only the `csv` module:

```
import csv

def read_csv(self, csv_path, delimiter):
    with open(csv_path, newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        # https://bugs.python.org/issue7185
        # Remove UTF8 BOM.
        txt = f.read()[1:]

    # Remove header line.
    header = txt.splitlines()[:1]
    lines = txt.splitlines()[1:]

    # Convert to list.
    csv_rows = list(csv.reader(lines, delimiter=delimiter))

    for row in csv_rows:
        value = row[INDEX_HERE]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution is to use csv.DictReader()

```
import csv

def read_csv(file): with open(file, 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in reader:
        print(row["column_name"])  # Replace the name of column header.
```