# How to skip the headers when processing a csv file using Python?

Tags: python, csv, csv-header

I am using below referred code to edit a csv using Python. Functions called in the code form upper part of the code.

Problem: I want the below referred code to start editing the csv from 2nd row, I want it to exclude 1st row which contains headers. Right now it is applying the functions on 1st row only and my header row is getting changed.

```
in_file = open("tmob_notcleaned.csv", "rb")
reader = csv.reader(in_file)
out_file = open("tmob_cleaned.csv", "wb")
writer = csv.writer(out_file)
row = 1
for row in reader:
    row[13] = handle_color(row[10])[1].replace(" - ","").strip()
    row[10] = handle_color(row[10])[0].replace("-","").replace("(","").replace(")","").strip()
    row[14] = handle_gb(row[10])[1].replace("-","").replace(" ","").replace("GB","").strip()
    row[10] = handle_gb(row[10])[0].strip()
    row[9] = handle_oem(row[10])[1].replace("Blackberry","RIM").replace("TMobile","T-Mobile").strip()
    row[15] = handle_addon(row[10])[1].strip()
    row[10] = handle_addon(row[10])[0].replace(" by","").replace("FREE","").strip()
    writer.writerow(row)
in_file.close()    
out_file.close()
```

I tried to solve this problem by initializing `row` variable to `1` but it didn't work.

Please help me in solving this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When processing CSV data, how do I ignore the first line of data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349333/when-processing-csv-data-how-do-i-ignore-the-first-line-of-data)

Answer (score 530, accepted):

Your `reader` variable is an iterable, by looping over it you retrieve the rows.

To make it skip one item before your loop, simply call [`next(reader, None)`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) and ignore the return value.

You can also simplify your code a little; use the opened files as context managers to have them closed automatically:

```
with open("tmob_notcleaned.csv", "rb") as infile, open("tmob_cleaned.csv", "wb") as outfile:
   reader = csv.reader(infile)
   next(reader, None)  # skip the headers
   writer = csv.writer(outfile)
   for row in reader:
       # process each row
       writer.writerow(row)

# no need to close, the files are closed automatically when you get to this point.
```

If you wanted to write the header to the output file unprocessed, that's easy too, pass the output of `next()` to `writer.writerow()`:

```
headers = next(reader, None)  # returns the headers or `None` if the input is empty
if headers:
    writer.writerow(headers)
```

Comment: An alternative is also to use `for row in islice(reader, 1, None)` - although less explicit than `next` for most simple "skip one line" jobs, for skipping multiple header rows (or getting only certain chunks etc...) it's quite handy

Comment: I'd consider using `try: writer.write(next(reader))... except StopIteration: # handle empty reader`

Comment: @JonClements: Perhaps. This works well enough without having to teach about `try:` / `except:`.

Comment: @JonClements: Advantage to explicit `next` iteration is that it's "free"; `islice` would wrap the `reader` forever adding (an admittedly very small amount of) overhead to each iteration. The [`consume` recipe from `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) can be used to skip many values quickly, without adding wrapping to subsequent usage, in the case where the `islice` would have a `start` but no `end`, so the overhead isn't gaining you anything.

Answer (score 177):

Another way of solving this is to use the DictReader class, which "skips" the header row and uses it to allowed named indexing.

Given "foo.csv" as follows:

```
FirstColumn,SecondColumn
asdf,1234
qwer,5678
```

Use DictReader like this:

```
import csv
with open('foo.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        print(row['FirstColumn'])  # Access by column header instead of column number
        print(row['SecondColumn'])
```

Comment: I feel like this is the real answer, as the question seems to be an example of [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: DictReader is definitely the way to go

Comment: It is important to note that this only works if you omit the field names parameter when constructing the DictReader. Per the documentation: `If the fieldnames parameter is omitted, the values in the first row of the file f will be used as the fieldnames.` See https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Answer (score 16):

Doing `row=1` won't change anything, because you'll just overwrite that with the results of the loop.

You want to do `next(reader)` to skip one row.

Comment: I tried changing it to `for row in next(reader):` but it is giving me `IndexError: string index out of range` error

Comment: Use it before the for loop: `next(reader); for row in reader:` ....

Answer (score 11):

Simply iterate one time with next()

```
with open(filename) as file:

    csvreaded = csv.reader(file)
    header = next(csvreaded)

    for row in csvreaded:
        empty_list.append(row) #your csv list without header
```

or use [1:] at the end of reader object

```
with open(filename) as file:

    csvreaded = csv.reader(file)
    header = next(csvreaded)

    for row in csvreaded[1:]:
        empty_list.append(row) #your csv list without header
```

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by Martijn Pieters' response.

In case you only need to delete the header from the `csv` file, you can work more efficiently if you write using the standard Python file I/O library, avoiding writing with the CSV Python library:

```py
with open("tmob_notcleaned.csv", "rb") as infile, open("tmob_cleaned.csv", "wb") as outfile:
   next(infile)  # skip the headers
   outfile.write(infile.read())
```

Comment: You seem to overlook the `# process each row` part in Martijn's answer, which stands for all the stuff the op wants to with the rows, as well as the fact that the op wants a _csv-file as output_? Of course you can avoid using the `csv` module altogether. But what's the point, it's from the _standard_ library?

Comment: In my case, I only want to remove the header from the `csv` file, and I don't want to process anything. For this reason, I write using the standard library, because it is faster.

I will edit my comment to be more clear.

Comment: I see. In that case you don't need the `csv` module at all: Just `next(infile)` without instantiating a `csv.reader` should do it (the output of `open` is also an iterator).

Answer (score -1):

```
with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file, fieldnames=None)
    # for some reason fieldnames=None causes first row to be skipped
    for row in reader: 
        print(row) # so the the first row printed is second row in file
```