# How is this code converted into python 2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

```
import csv

with open('scores.csv') as handle:
    reader = csv.reader(handle)
    for row in list(reader)[1:]:
        user, *scores = row
        average = sum([int(score) for score in scores]) / len(scores)
        print (
            "{user} has average of {average}".format(user=user,average=average)
        )
```

This code won't work in python 2.7 because of the *scores. How do I change this into python 2.7 as I don't know how?

This code was taken from this thread: [Row Average CSV Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27960831/row-average-csv-python/27962423#27962423)

Comment: You'll also need to adjust the `average` line. In Python 3, `/` is "true division", but not in Python 2 -- the result will be truncated to an integer, instead. The simplest way would be by casting one of the values to a `float` first.

Comment: Note that using `list(reader)[1:]` is hugely inefficient as that pulls everything in the file into a list. Use `next(reader, None)` on a separate line, then `for row in reader:` instead; that'll read one line from the CSV and discard it, effectively skipping that one row. See [Skip the headers when editing a csv file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14257599)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the line

```
user, *scores = row
```

to

```
user, scores = row[0], row[1:]
```

Note apart from the above, you should also change

```
average = sum([int(score) for score in scores]) / len(scores)
```

to

```
average = sum([int(score) for score in scores]) / float(len(scores))
```

as division in Python 2.X is integer division. Alternatively, you can also import real division from future

```
from __future__ import division
```

and to use integer division use double forward slash '//'

Answer (score 1):

you should make our code so compatible with python 3 as possible, with future imports:

```
from __future__ import division, print_function
import csv

with open('scores.csv') as handle:
    reader = csv.reader(handle)
    next(reader) # header
    for row in reader:
        user = row[0]
        scores = row[1:]
        average = sum(int(score) for score in scores) / len(scores)
        print (
        "{user} has average of {average}".format(user=user, average=average)
        )
```