# StopIteration when use csv in python2

Tags: python, csv

In my code there is a function contains a csv reader like following

```
def preprocessing_file(file_path):
    out = []
    with open(file_path,'r') as f_in:
        lines = csv.reader(f_in)
        next(lines)
        out.append(lines)
    return out
```

when I run this code the terminal shows me messages below

```
  File "preprocessing.py", line 14, in preprocessing_file
    next(lines)
StopIteration
```

This problem occur after I make these section a function, before it the code works fine.

Anyone know whats the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You opened an empty file; there are no rows to iterate over. You can tell `next()` to suppress the exception by giving it a default value to return:

```
next(lines, None)
```

See [Skip the headers when editing a csv file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257373/skip-the-headers-when-editing-a-csv-file-using-python).

Note that your `out.append(lines)` line appends the *CSV reader object* to your list, not the rows in the CSV. I'd use `out = list(lines)` for that instead, or just return the reader itself with `return lines`.