# CSV to List of Dictionaries - Better Way?

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I'm working on a function that takes in a filename of a CSV and converts each line to a dictionary and then returns a list of the dictionaries created (to be able to iterate through and organize in later functions.  I've gotten it to do what I want by doing the following but feel there's got to be a better way.  Any suggestions for improvement?

```
import re

def import_incidents(filename):
    """Imports CSV and returns list of dictionaries for each incident"""
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        data = file.read()
        data = data.split('\n')
        list_of_data = []
        headers = True
        for line in data:
            line = line.split('","')
            if headers == True:
                #Skip header and set to false
                headers = False
            elif len(line) == 1 or line[3] == '':
                #File always has a 1 lenth final line, skip it.
                #Events can leave blank policies, skip those too.
                pass
            else:
                temp_dict = {}
                temp_dict['id'] = re.sub('"', '', line[0])
                temp_dict['time'] = re.sub('GMT-0600','',line[1])
                temp_dict['source'] = line[2]
                temp_dict['policy'] = line[3]
                temp_dict['destination'] = line[5]
                temp_dict['status'] = line[10]
                list_of_data.append(temp_dict)

return list_of_data

print(import_incidents('Incidents (Yesterday Only).csv'))
```

Sample of CSV contents:

```
"ID","Incident Time","Source","Policies","Channel","Destination","Severity","Action","Maximum Matches","Transaction Size","Status",
"9511564","29 Dec. 2015, 08:33:59 AM GMT-0600","Doe, John","Encrypted files","HTTPS","blah.blah.com","Medium","Permitted","0","47.7 KB","Closed - Authorized",
"1848446","29 Dec. 2015, 08:23:36 AM GMT-0600","Smith, Joe","","HTTP","google.com","Low","Permitted","0","775 B","Closed"
```

Comment: Have a look at csv.DictReader: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have reinvented the [`csv.DictReader()` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader), I'm afraid:

```
import csv

def import_incidents(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r', newline='') as file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file)
        for row in reader:
            if not row or not row['Policies']:
                continue
            row['Incident Time'] = re.sub('GMT-0600', '', row['Incident Time'])
            yield row
```

This relies on the header row for the dictionary keys. You can define your own dictionary keys with the `fieldnames` argument to `DictReader()` (the `fieldnames` field is matched, in order, to the columns in the file), but then the first row in the file is still read like any other row. You can use the `next()` function to skip rows (see [Skip the headers when editing a csv file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257373/skip-the-headers-when-editing-a-csv-file-using-python/14257599#14257599)).

Comment: Ha!  Great.  Good to know it's been done before now.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I documented my assumption about the header. The 'empty line' can be skipped with `if not row or not row['policy']: continue`.

Comment: Getting:    <generator object import_incidents at 0x0000005CA2C94830>

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: `csv.DictReader()` handles quotes properly.

Comment: @user987654321: yes, I produced a generator function, not a list. Use iteration (like a `for` loop), or call `list()` on that generator object to produce a list again.

Comment: @user987654321: however, unless you need random access to any of the rows at any time, I'd use iteration and not read the whole file into memory.

Comment: Working like a charm and feeling like a fool.  Thanks @MartijnPieters.

Answer (score 1):

### Original task: List of dicts

You can use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/). It is fast and can do it in a few lines;

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('incidents.csv')
df['Incident Time'] = df['Incident Time'].str.replace('GMT-0600', '')
list_of_data = df.dropna(subset=['Policies']).to_dict(orient='records')
```

Now `list_of_data` contains:

```
[{'Action': 'Permitted',
  'Channel': 'HTTPS',
  'Destination': 'blah.blah.com',
  'ID': 9511564,
  'Incident Time': '29 Dec. 2015, 08:33:59 AM ',
  'Maximum Matches': 0,
  'Policies': 'Encrypted files',
  'Severity': 'Medium',
  'Source': 'Doe, John',
  'Status': 'Closed - Authorized',
  'Transaction Size': '47.7 KB',
  'Unnamed: 11': nan}]
```

The `.dropna(subset='Policies')` removes the lines that have `NaN`s in the column `Policies`, i.e. missing values.

### Pandas-only solution:

If you don't want the list of dicts, keep the dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_csv('incidents.csv', parse_dates=[1]).dropna(subset=['Policies'])
```

This reads the `Incident Time` as very convenient `datetime64[ns]`object. The dataframe looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Would there be any additional advantages to working with pandas?

Comment: Yes. You don`t need to convert the dataframe into a list of dicts in the first place. It si way more powerful than a plain dictionary or list. It is also really fast when used in the right way. Lots of it is written in Cython for speed.

Comment: What's the .dropna(subset='Policies') for?

Comment: Also... have a strange character that is picked up in reading the .csv.. instead of the "ID" i get a \ufeff"ID" from the file need to input.  Some sort of special character inserted (my guess).  Any way to have this be stripped off?

Comment: Your file has a byteorder mark (BOM). Try to open the file with the encoding `utf-8-sig`: `pd.read_csv('incidents.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig')`.