# Python: execute for loop only once(not the first time but second time)?

Tags: python, csv

fileInput consists of a csv file with some 30 rows and I want to access only the second row.

`for row in csv.reader(fileInput):`

I need to access the second row not the first one(first one contains col names). `row[1]` gives second column in `row0`?

***only the second row not from the first row!***

Comment: You can assign `csv.reader` to a variable `my_csv` and iterate through each line. To skip a line you can use `next` as mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14257599/378704)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider using [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader). It'll handle the header for you and allow you to access the columns by name rather than index (which can help with keeping code readable).

eg.

```
import csv

with open('names.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    row = next(reader)
    print(row['first_name'], row['last_name'])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
r = csv.reader(f)
first_line = next(r)
second_line = next(r)
for line in r:
    print(line) #rest of the lines
```

`reader` returns an iterator: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader

Comment: I like this better than a `break` in `for` loop, but note that `StopIteration` may be raised

Comment: Yeah, but if there aren't at least two lines in the input then the question doesn't make any sense and an exception should be raised