# Read data of a CSV file to create a new CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have some data on a CSV file. As you can see in the code, I can read the file and print the info I need. The problem is when I try to create a new CSV file with some info of Original CSV file. I would like to save my `analyzed` info in a new CSV. I don't know how to use the original info to make a new file.

Data.csv
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8E7t.png)

```
import csv

with open('Data.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV:
        analyzed = (row[0],row[3],row[3]<0.25)
        print(analyzed)
```

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for how to write data to a CSV. The fact it came from another CSV isn't too relevant here. If you look up how to write data to a CSV you should be in good shape.

Comment: check this dup : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257373/skip-the-headers-when-editing-a-csv-file-using-python/14257599#14257599, except the skipping header part...

Comment: I'd start with the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) documentation. There's lots of examples.

Comment: Thanks @PRMoureu It was very helpful!

Comment: @displayname, I'm not sure editing their code, even if its just to correct mispelled variable names, is the right thing to do. Not sure though.

Comment: @TankorSmash Let's not forget the upper case .. I agree with you and I'm usually not doing that but in that case the worst case scenario is he, from now on, remembers how to spell it right :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) when it comes to CSV files or table-like data:

```
import pandas as pd

df_data = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('Data.csv')

# Analyze
for index, row in df_data.iterrows():
    pass

df_data.to_csv('new_Data.csv')
```

For reading you have several options like

- [`pandas.DataFrame.from_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_csv.html)
- [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)
- [`pandas.read_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html)

and, as you see, use

- [`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

to save your transformed or newly created `DataFrame`.

For installation run

```
pip install pandas
```