# Creating nested dictionary from 3 different CSV files

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter

My aim is to take the data from 3 different CSV file and create a nested dictionary, I realize my error, but I fail to fix it.

Shall I create 3 different methods for each file to iterate the data and then create the nested dictionary, or it is something else that I have to do?

Code:

```
class STproject:

    def __init__(self,app): #1
        self.mlb=LabelFrame(app, text='Movie Recommendation Engine')
        self.mlb.grid()
        self.lframe3=LabelFrame(self.mlb,text="Movies/Users",background='purple')
        self.lframe3.grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.framebutton=Frame(self.mlb,background='pink',height=50,width=50)
        self.framebutton.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.buttonsnlabels()

    def buttonsnlabels(self):
        self.ratingbutton=Button(self.framebutton,text='Upload movies',command=lambda :self.file1())
        self.ratingbutton.grid()
        self.ratingbutton=Button(self.framebutton,text='Upload ratings',command=lambda :self.file2())
        self.ratingbutton.grid()
        self.ratingbutton=Button(self.framebutton,text='Upload links',command=lambda :self.file3())
        self.ratingbutton.grid()

    def file1(self):
        umovies=tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
        f=open(umovies)
        self.csv_file1 = csv.reader(f)
        self.dictionary()

    def file2(self):
        uratings=tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
        f=open(uratings)
        self.csv_file2 = csv.reader(f)
        self.dictionary()

    def file3(self):
        links=tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
        f=open(links)
        self.csv_file3 = csv.reader(f)
        self.dictionary()

    def dictionary(self):
        for line1,line2,line3 in zip(self.csv_file1,self.csv_file2,self.csv_file3):
            dict={}
            dict[line1]={[line2]:[line3]}

root=Tk()
root.title()
application=STproject(root)
root.mainloop()
```

and this is the error given:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1547, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Umer Selmani/Desktop/voluntarily/Voluntiraly.py", line 825, in <lambda>
    self.ratingbutton=Button(self.framebutton,text='Upload movies',command=lambda :self.file1())
  File "C:/Users/Umer Selmani/Desktop/voluntarily/Voluntiraly.py", line 836, in file1
    self.dictionary()
  File "C:/Users/Umer Selmani/Desktop/voluntarily/Voluntiraly.py", line 858, in dictionary
    for line1,line2,line3 in zip(self.csv_file1,self.csv_file2,self.csv_file3):
AttributeError: STproject instance has no attribute 'csv_file2'
```

Comment: You should only call the `dictionary` method after all 3 files are read. Calling them prematurely will result in the `AttributeError` since it has not been defined yet.

Comment: Also, you don't close your CSV files anywhere. Consider 1) keeping only the paths as attributes and open and close them inside the `dictionary` function or 2) store the contents as attributes and close the files after inside the `file<n>` functions. You also keep instantiating your `dict` inside the for loop in the `dictionary` method, meaning you'll only store the last line in the files.

Comment: @HenryYik, so i have to call the **dictionary**, in the first (**__init__**) method, or shall i, shrink all three **file** method in to one and assign it to each **button**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to first store the selected results at a place, and process them later by another button. In the below sample i'm using `StringVar` to store the file paths.

```
class STproject:

    def __init__(self, app):
        self.mlb=LabelFrame(app, text='Movie Recommendation Engine')
        self.mlb.grid()
        self.lframe3=LabelFrame(self.mlb,text="Movies/Users",background='purple')
        self.lframe3.grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.framebutton=Frame(self.mlb,background='pink',height=50,width=50)
        self.framebutton.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.buttonsnlabels()
        self.all_vars = [StringVar() for _ in range(3)]

    def buttonsnlabels(self):
        self.ratingbutton=Button(self.framebutton,text='Upload movies',command=lambda:self.file(self.all_vars[0]))
        self.ratingbutton.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.ratingbutton=Button(self.framebutton,text='Upload ratings',command=lambda:self.file(self.all_vars[1]))
        self.ratingbutton.grid(row=1,column=0)
        self.ratingbutton=Button(self.framebutton,text='Upload links',command=lambda:self.file(self.all_vars[2]))
        self.ratingbutton.grid(row=2,column=0)
        self.process = Button(self.framebutton,text='Process',command=self.dictionary)
        self.process.grid(row=1,column=1)

    def file(self, v):
        result = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
        if result:
            v.set(result)

    def dictionary(self):
        if all(i.get() for i in self.all_vars): #process only if all 3 files are selected
            with open(self.all_vars[0].get(),"r") as a, open(self.all_vars[1].get(),"r") as b, open(self.all_vars[2].get(),"r") as c:
                d = {}
                for line1,line2,line3 in zip(csv.reader(a),csv.reader(b),csv.reader(c)):
                    d[line1]={line2:line3}

root=Tk()
root.title()
application=STproject(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Note that I also moved the location and the name of the `dict` in your original code. In your code, not other it shadows the built in method `dict`, it also overwrites itself during each iteration of the `for` loop, which i think would not be what you looking for.

Comment: self.all_vars[0]=self.all_vars[0][1:]
self.all_vars[1]=self.all_vars[1][1:]
is this the right code for skipping the first row?

Comment: apperantly that code did not work, can you explain how it might be done?

Comment: No - the `StringVar` only stored the path to the file. To skip headers, you can take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257373/skip-the-headers-when-editing-a-csv-file-using-python).

Comment: Thank You for your help. May God bless you.