# Python Loop: string Index Out of Range

Tags: python, csv, bar-chart

Given the following csv file:

```
['offre_bfr.entreprise', 'offre_bfr.nombreemp', 'offre_bfr.ca2020', 'offre_bfr.ca2019', 'offre_bfr.ca2018', 'offre_bfr.benefice2020', 'offre_bfr.benefice2019', 'offre_bfr.benefice2018', 'offre_bfr.tauxrenta2020', 'offre_bfr.tauxrenta2019', 'offre_bfr.tauxrenta2018', 'offre_bfr.tauximposition', 'offre_bfr.chargesalariale', 'offre_bfr.chargesfixes', 'offre_bfr.agedirigeant', 'offre_bfr.partdirigeant', 'offre_bfr.agemoyact', 'offre_bfr.parttotaleact', 'offre_bfr.mtdmdcred', 'offre_bfr.creditusuel', 'offre_bfr.capipropres', 'offre_bfr.dettefin', 'offre_bfr.dettenonfin', 'offre_bfr.stock', 'offre_bfr.creances', 'offre_bfr.actifimmobilise', 'offre_bfr.passiftotal', 'offre_bfr.tresorerie', 'offre_bfr.capitalisation2020', 'offre_bfr.capitalisation2019', 'offre_bfr.capitalisation2018', 'offre_bfr.nivrisque', 'offre_bfr.indconfiance', 'offre_bfr.indperseverance', 'offre_bfr.score']
['1', '15', '1.84', '5.18', '7.96', '0.48', '1.19', '0.11', '26.086956', '22.972973', '1.3819095', '17.9', '0.035295', '1.2', '55', '33', '69', '67', '10', '14.98', '0.05', '0.04', '0.21', '0.1', '0.08', '0.41', '0.8', '0.0', '7.5', '52.8', '0.16', 'Bas', '4', '4', '5.0']
['3', '3030', '546.7', '589.7', '430.9', '62.58', '20.63', '99.06', '11.446863', '3.498389', '22.989092', '17.4', '7.12959', '270.9', '46', '37', '69', '73', '2973', '1567.3', '46.97', '13.39', '61.92', '3.0', '8.0', '145.0', '278.4', '-51.0', '1063.5', '3047.8', '538.08', 'Eleve', '4', '4', '3.0']
['4', '42', '4.28', '9.13', '8.99', '0.45', '0.59', '0.08', '10.514019', '6.4622126', '0.8898776', '31.5', '0.098826', '2.2', '70', '32', '53', '68', '9', '22.4', '0.13', '0.06', '0.31', '0.1', '0.07', '0.92', '1.7', '-0.3', '42.5', '69.5', '2.73', 'Eleve', '4', '4', '3.0']
['5', '497', '92.2', '62.5', '40.3', '20.14', '6.91', '4.92', '21.843819', '11.056', '12.208437', '32.2', '1.169441', '5.1', '64', '32', '70', '68', '197', '195.0', '6.07', '1.83', '12.49', '5.9', '3.83', '16.41', '16.5', '-2.7', '1048.3', '618.8', '11.24', 'Moyen', '4', '4', '4.0']
['8', '122', '67.8', '24.5', '91.4', '12.67', '5.69', '8.43', '18.687315', '23.22449', '9.223195', '24.8', '0.287066', '19.5', '53', '35', '61', '65', '424', '183.7', '1.64', '1.92', '6.48', '4.9', '2.45', '23.6', '23.7', '-3.5', '204.2', '109.5', '5.33', 'Eleve', '4', '4', '3.0']
['11', '310', '77.5', '78.7', '24.9', '8.05', '21.76', '1.79', '10.387096', '27.649302', '7.188755', '29.0', '0.72943', '12.0', '47', '32', '65', '68', '38', '181.1', '6.55', '3.27', '8.16', '5.1', '2.08', '15.09', '36.3', '-7.0', '669.8', '705.3', '22.95', 'Eleve', '4', '4', '3.0']
['14', '283', '91.9', '52.9', '51.9', '10.48', '7.01', '12.57', '11.4037', '13.251418', '24.219654', '24.2', '0.665899', '2.3', '61', '29', '58', '71', '60', '196.7', '8.02', '2.93', '7.79', '7.0', '3.87', '25.1', '42.7', '-4.4', '434.0', '143.4', '17.18', 'Eleve', '4', '4', '3.0']
['16', '41', '5.54', '6.48', '5.5', '1.55', '1.51', '0.73', '27.97834', '23.30247', '13.272727', '15.9', '0.096473', '2.4', '71', '39', '56', '61', '29', '17.52', '0.41', '0.11', '0.62', '0.3', '0.17', '1.47', '2.4', '0.0', '36.7', '76.0', '4.2', 'Bas', '4', '4', '5.0']
```

I would like to create a bar chart from columns 0 and 34 of the csv file.
Here is the python script I am running:

```
# -*-coding:Latin-1 -*
#!/usr/bin/python
#!/usr/bin/env python

import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
  
x = []
y = []
Bfr = csv.reader(open('/home/cloudera/PMGE/Bfr.csv​'))
linesBfr = list(Bfr)
i=1
for l in linesBfr:
        x.append(l[i][0])
    y.append(int(l[i][34]))
  
plt.bar(x, y, color = 'g', width = 0.72, label = "Score")
plt.xlabel('Entreprise')
plt.ylabel('Scores')
plt.title('Scores des entreprises en BFR')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

But i'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "barplot.py", line 20, in <module>
    y.append(int(l[i][34]))
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: What does: `l[i][34]` mean to you?

Comment: You probably don't need `i` as index in `l[i][0]` and `l[i][34]` to iterate through the rows of the csv file? Since `l` is essentially a value row in linesBfr. So you probably just need `x.append(l[0])` and `y.append(int(l[34]))`

Answer (score 0):

Python lists are zero-indexed. You are trying to iterate to the 35th element in a 34 element list.

Comment: Oh, I think that each list has 35 elements.

Comment: Yes I know, my list contains 35 elements and therefore to access the last element I point to the index 34

Comment: Good that you verified that. I think the answer likely has to do with the [i] in your syntax. More specifically, it is looking for a list that doesn't exist, based on the way each of the lists in your input are unique (IE, you are not actually dealing with a list of lists).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there are 35 elements from 0 to 34. This means that starting your indexing i at i=1 will look for an element at the 35th index, which does not exist, or be an "index out of range". To be more specific, your code is looking for a list that does not exist. Secondly, this is not the standard way to use 2d lists in python. I suggest using a method more as such:

[https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-append-to-a-2d-list-in-python#:~:text=Append%20a%20list%20to%20a,list%20to%20the%202D%20list](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-append-to-a-2d-list-in-python#:%7E:text=Append%20a%20list%20to%20a,list%20to%20the%202D%20list).

Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant to write this:

```py
x = []
y = []
Bfr = csv.reader(open('/home/cloudera/PMGE/Bfr.csv​'))
next(Bfr , None) # skip the header
for l in Bfr:
    x.append(int(l[0]))
    y.append(int(l[34]))
...
```

(See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257373/skip-the-headers-when-editing-a-csv-file-using-python) about skipping the header of a csv)

Comment: I just tried this but still the same error

Comment: That sounds most unlikely. Are you sure it’s a string index out of range?