# Adding rows with csv.writer.writerow / csv.writer.writerows is removing headers / columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Been testing with some data management techniques with pandas and csv. What I'm trying to do is read a csv file, add some extra rows to it, and save again with identical format.

I've created a dataframe of shape (250, 20) with random values, dates as index and alphabets as columns then saved it as a csv file. Ultimately what I've tried is to append the same dataframe below an existing csv file.

```
def _writeBulk(savefile, data):
    df = data.reset_index()
    with open(savefile, 'w', newline='') as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        writer.writerows(df.to_numpy().tolist())
        outfile.close()

def _writeData(savefile, data):
    df = data.reset_index()
    with open(savefile, 'w', newline='') as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        for row in range(df.shape[0]):
            writer.writerow(df.iloc[row].tolist())
        outfile.close()
```

When reading in the file again after edit, the result I'm expecting is a dataframe of shape (500,20). But it seems that the file does not have headers(columns) anymore, with shape (499, 200).

[image]

I've searched for solutions or explanations but skipping the header while writing rows is the closest I've ever got to the actual issue.

> [Skip the headers when editing a csv file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257373/skip-the-headers-when-editing-a-csv-file-using-python)

Any explanations or solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: 1. Headers: Either add writer.writeheaders or use csv.DictWriter. 2. "I've tried is to append the same dataframe below an existing csv file." - 'w' mode will overwrite your whole file, not append. Any existing headers and all existing rows will be lost

Comment: Cnt believed I haven't noticed that... thank you very much. I'll try the 'a' mode instead.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if your .csv has the first column as date (also the index), when you read that file into a DataFrame you don't have to use .reset_index()

For example, you csv might look like this in Excel:
[image]

When you read that to a dataframe it becomes:

[image]

If you simply want to append a new DataFrame with the same number of columns Date, A,B,C... you can simply do so:

```
source_df = pd.read_csv('initial.csv')

# copy of the same dataframe
# it could be a different df as per your requirement
new_df = source_df.copy()

# appending the 2nd dataframe to the 1st
final_df = source_df.append(new_df)

# writing to .csv
final_df.to_csv('final.csv', index=False)
```

We're setting the index=False to avoid DateFrame default indexing (0,1,2,3...) to be written to the final .csv file

Your final df is going to look like:

[image]

And when viewed in Excel:

[image]

Having said all this, if you want your DataFrame to have date as the index, but when you write to .csv, it should have columns data, A,B,C,...

Do this:

```
source_df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

# copy of the same dataframe
new_df = source_df.copy()

# appending the 2nd dataframe to the 1st
final_df = source_df.append(new_df)

final_df.set_index(['date'], inplace=True)
final_df.to_csv('final.csv')
```

And you'll have, df:

[image]

And when viewed in Excel:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. The data parameter is the dataframe that is already in memory, with dates as index. So before writing rows, I had to reset the index for list conversion. I've chosen this method since the data I'm supposed to actually work with has 1e8 rows & I don't think reading in the whole thing and concatenating it will be a good idea. Do you have any sort of suggestions that effectively concatenates such large datasets?