# Skip first line(field) in loop using CSV file?

Tags: python, csv, for-loop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When processing CSV data, how do I ignore the first line of data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349333/when-processing-csv-data-how-do-i-ignore-the-first-line-of-data)

I am using python to open CSV file. I am using formula loop but I need to skip the first row because it has header.

So far I remember was something like this but it is missing something: I wonder if someone knows the code for what I am trying to do.

```
for row in kidfile:
    if row.firstline = false:  # <====== Something is missing here.
        continue
    if ......
```

Comment: Why would someone show you but not let you take notes, and why is that relevant to your question?

Comment: Use `csv_data.__next__()` for 3.x and `csv_data.next()` for 2.x.  More details are https://stackoverflow.com/a/63096202/10961238

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The best way of doing this is skipping the header *after* passing the file object to the `csv` module:

```
with open('myfile.csv', 'r', newline='') as in_file:
    reader = csv.reader(in_file)
    # skip header
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        # handle parsed row
```

This handles multiline CSV headers correctly.

---

Older answer:

Probably you want something like:

```
firstline = True
for row in kidfile:
    if firstline:    #skip first line
        firstline = False
        continue
    # parse the line
```

An other way to achive the same result is calling `readline` before the loop:

```
kidfile.readline()   # skip the first line
for row in kidfile:
    #parse the line
```

Comment: The `next` function is a much more concise approach.

Comment: If one of the values in the first row can contain a newline `\n` character, this won't work.

Answer (score 140):

There are many ways to skip the first line. In addition to those said by Bakuriu, I would add:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    next(f)
    for line in f:
```

and:

```
with open(filename,'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()[1:]
```

Comment: If one of the values in the first row can contain a newline `\n` character, this won't work.

Answer (score 28):

csvreader.next()
Return the next row of the reader’s iterable object as a list, parsed according to the current dialect.

Comment: In python3, the method is `reader.__next__()`, which should be called by using `next(reader)`