# pg8000 copy from CSV

Tags: python, csv, google-app-engine, pg8000

I'm using [pg8000](http://pythonhosted.org/pg8000/) on an App Engine flask application so that I can be able to process a CSV file and insert it into a PSQL instance (hosted on `AZURE`).

Why am I using `pg8000` and not `psycopg2`? -> Because app engine doesn't support psycopg2.

So far, the docs of `pg8000` don't state a function that will do this like the one psycopg2 has. I haven't found an example that achieves this on SO or any other place, including the docs.

Anyone knows if this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/mfenniak/pg8000/), there does not seem to be a way to directly import CSVs, nor does the code appear to have any built-in wrapper around `INSERT` queries, making it possible to

You do have the option of manually using a CSV reader and using `executemany`:

```
import csv
import pg8000

conn = pg8000.connect(user="postgres", password="C.P.Snow")
cursor = conn.cursor()

command = 'INSERT INTO book (title) VALUES (%s), (%s) RETURNING id, title'
with open('my-data.csv', 'rb') as fl:
    data = list(csv.reader(fl))
    conn.executemany(command, data)
```

As a word of caution, depending on the size of your data, it may be better to use [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
with open('my-data.csv', 'rb') as fl:
    reader = csv.reader(fl)
    slice = itertool.islice(reader, 100)
    while slice:
        conn.executemany(command, slice)
        slice = itertool.islice(reader, 100)
```

Comment: This works fine, but throws the following error: `ProgrammingError: (u'ERROR', u'ERROR', u'42601', u'INSERT has more target columns than expressions', u'79', u'analyze.c', u'884', u'transformInsertRow')`, can you assist me with this? One of the columns is autoincrement and not specified in the insert statement.

Comment: That's a SQL error. You should try to get your SQL working first, and then plug it into `executemany`.

Comment: fixed! however it takes so much time to process. Instead of inserting, can't we use the copy command?

Comment: @codeninja mysql supports load infile - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html . This should be a lot faster instead of individual inserts. Also be sure to disable and enable keys if you have any on your tables during inserts.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674275/skip-first-linefield-in-loop-using-csv-file), you could use the `next` method before applying the logic on the csv files and before using the csv read method.

Sorry in advance for not inserting as a complement to the previous answer, but I don't have enough points to do so.

I'm having the same issue and I solved the problem using the below. Please notice that for me, the correct way of executing many is on `cursor` object, not on the `conn`.

```
conn = pg8000.connect(user='username', password='password', host='host', port=5432, database='database name')
cursor = conn.cursor()

command = "INSERT INTO public.salesforce_accounts (field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
with open('test.csv', 'r') as file:
    next(file)
    data = list(csv.reader(file))
    cursor.executemany(command, data)
```

Answer (score 0):

All these methods were too slow for me. When working with large data, it seems like the COPY command works really well. This runs in a couple of seconds VS the 10 minutes from other methods.

```
# Import pandas and sqlalchemy libraries
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy

# Create a database connection pool
pool = sqlalchemy.create_engine() # Fill with login/pg8000 connector

# Read data into dataframe from a csv file
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

# Alternatively, create a dataframe from a dictionary of data
# df = pd.Dataframe(data)

# Create an empty buffer to store the csv data
buffer = StringIO()

# Write the dataframe to the buffer without the index column
df.to_csv(buffer, index=False)

# Open a raw connection to the database
connPG8K = pool.raw_connection()

# Create a cursor object to execute queries
cursor = connPG8K.cursor()

# Reset the buffer position to the beginning
buffer.seek(0)

# Copy the data from the buffer to the database table using the csv format and header option. 
# Table must exist. Will overwrite that table.
cursor.execute('COPY "OverwriteTable" FROM STDIN WITH (FORMAT csv, HEADER);', stream=buffer)

# Commit the changes to the database
connPG8K.commit()
```