# Access GCP Cloud SQL from AI notebook?

Tags: python, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

Looking for relevant python code to be used in the GCP AI Platform **notebook** which will be able to query GCP Cloud SQL (specifically Postgresql.) Unfortunately, I haven't found any relevat resources/tutorials from GCP official or even unaffiliated resources.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I work on the Developer Relations team for Cloud SQL at Google. The quickest and simplest way to connect to a Cloud SQL instance from an AI Platform Notebook is to use our newly released [Cloud SQL Python Connector](https://pypi.org/project/cloud-sql-python-connector/0.1.0/). To install, run `pip install cloud-sql-python-connector[pg8000]`. This will also install the pg8000 driver which is used to connect to Postgres.

Then, you can use the following code to get a connection object which you can use to run queries:

```
conn = connector.connect(
    "project_name:region-name:instance-name", 
    "pg8000",
    user="postgres",
    password="password",
    db="db_name"
)
```

An alternative, which is language-independent, is to download and run the [Cloud SQL Auth Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/sql-proxy) in a separate terminal from your notebook.

For either of these solutions, make sure to enable the [Cloud SQL Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/admin-api#enabling_the_api) first.

Comment: This connector is great, but still in alpha. Use it with caution!

Comment: FYI, we're working to get it from preview status to a GA release soon. Please let us know if you run into any issues. Thanks!

Comment: Quick follow up, if I need to stream in a csv file, I see that postgresql's copy function is generally preferred. Is there an analogous function/method in the Cloud SQL Python Connector?

Comment: The python connector isn't a SQL client itself. It's a sort of wrapper around other SQL clients (pg8000 for postgres). You can use the returned connection from the python connector just as you would use a pg8000 connection object. Here's an example of how to import a csv using a pg8000 connection: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47757873/pg8000-copy-from-csv