# How do I skip lines and parse dates as index in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file that contains 90000 lines with a date format index. I don't need to read the first 9 lines because that's info that doesn't concern me. I've tried like this:

```
df_dados = pd.read_csv('dados.csv', skiplines=9, index_col=0, parse_dates=['timestamp'])
```

Unfortunally it doesn't work, and the only way I've surpassed this is by modifying the file which I wouldn't like to do. Is there a way to skip lines and set the time index?

Comment: Look if this is useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674275/skip-first-linefield-in-loop-using-csv-file

Give me a feedback ;)

Comment: I think the correct parameter name is `skiprows`, not `skiplines`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `skiprows` argument of [`pandas.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) can be either list-like, an integer, or a callable.

- **List-like**: Contains the line numbers to skip
- **Integer**: Contains the line number to skip
- **Callable**: Returns `True` or `False` depending on whether the row should be skipped or not.

Since you want to skip the first 9 lines, try passing `skiprows=range(9)`.

```py
df_dados = pd.read_csv('dados.csv', skiprows=range(9), index_col=0, parse_dates=['timestamp'])
```

*Note: The line numbers to skip are 0-indexed (first line is index `0`, second is index `1`, etc.).*

Comment: It worked worderfully. Thank you very much