# Python idiom to skip first line that match condition

Tags: python, parsing

I have a tab delimited data that looks like this:

```
Probes  FOO BAR
1452463_x_at    306.564     185.705 
1439374_x_at    393.742     330.495 
1426392_a_at    269.850     209.931 
1433432_x_at    636.145     487.012 
1415687_a_at    231.547     175.008 
1424736_at  248.926     189.500 
1435324_x_at    244.901     225.842 
1438688_at  180.511     187.407 
1426906_at  206.694     218.913
```

What I want to do is to parse the above data. But first will have to skip the line that starts with `Probes`. But why this line failed? What is the most common Pythonesque way to deal with these problem?

```
import sys
import csv
import re 

with open('Z100_data.txt','r') as tsvfile:
    tabreader = csv.reader(tsvfile,delimiter='\t')
    for row in tabreader:
        if re.match("^Probes",row):
            # He we try to skip the first line.
            continue
        else:

           print ', '.join(row)
```

Comment: `row` is a `list`; `re.match` doesn't know what to do with a list.  `re.match('Probes',row[0])` would work, though simply throwing away the first row is more efficient than testing *every* row.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Python to analyze CSV data, how do I ignore the first line of data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349333/using-python-to-analyze-csv-data-how-do-i-ignore-the-first-line-of-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pythonic way to deal with this is `next()`

```
with open('Z100_data.txt','r') as tsvfile
    tabreader = csv.reader(tsvfile,delimiter = '\t')
    next(tabreader) # skips the first line
    for row in tabreader:
        print ', '.join(row)
```

Comment: Use `csv.Sniffer().has_header` if you don't know in advance whether the header is there or not.

Comment: @wim that sounds like a better answer but I don't know enough about `csv` to write it up -- you can edit my answer or give your own!

Comment: Couldn't be bothered because it's a dupe and has already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11350095/674039), just wanted future readers to be able to see that comment :)

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
if re.match("^Probes",' '.join(row)):
```

or:

```
if "Probes" in row:
```

or:

```
if "Probes" == row[0].strip():
```

`csv.reader` returns you list of tuples from row split by delimiter. You tried to use `re` o list/tuple, while it works on strings only.