# Combine csv in Python with skipping header row Error

Tags: python

I've successfully combined all csv files in a directory, however struggling with the ability to skip the first row (header) of each file.  The error I currently get is " 'list' object is not an iterator".  I have tried multiple approaches including not using the [open(thefile).read()],  but still not able to get it working. Here is my code:

```
 import glob
 files = glob.glob( '*.csv' )
 output="combined.csv"

 with open(output, 'w' ) as result:
     for thefile in files:
         f = [open(thefile).read()]
         next(f)   ## this line is causing the error 'list' object is not an iterator

         for line in f:
             result.write( line )
 message = 'file created'
 print (message)
```

Comment: You should close each file after reading it, either explicitly, or using 'with' as you did opening the file to which you are writing.

Comment: You might find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349333/when-processing-csv-data-how-do-i-ignore-the-first-line-of-data/11350095#11350095) helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `readlines()` function instead of `read()`, so that you could easily skip the first line.

```
f = open(thefile)
m = f.readlines()
for line in m[1:]:
    result.write(line.rstrip())
f.close()
```

**OR**

```
with open(thefile) as f:
    m = f.readlines()
    for line in m[1:]:
        result.write(line.rstrip())
```

You don't need to explicitly close the file object if the file was opened through `with` statement.

Comment: @ Avinash Raj it's telling me "invalid syntax" at m[1:]

Comment: did you put the colon after `m[1:]` ?

Comment: when I use the exact example you gave it works, but does not keep same format as original files with each row of data on it's one line

Comment: try `result.write(line)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative using the oft forgotten [`fileinput.input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.input) method:

```
import fileinput
from glob import glob

FILE_PATTERN = '*.csv'
output = 'combined.csv'

with open(output, 'w') as output:
    for line in fileinput.input(glob(FILE_PATTERN)):
        if not fileinput.isfirstline():
            output.write(line)
```

It's quite a bit cleaner than many other solutions.

Note that the code in your question was not far off working. You just need to change

```
f = [open(thefile).read()]
```

to

```
f = open(thefile)
```

but I suggest that using `with` would be better still because it will automatically close the input files:

```
with open(output, 'w' ) as result:
    for thefile in files:
        with open(thefile) as f:
            next(f)
            for line in f:
                result.write( line )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> next(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list object is not an iterator
```

I am not sure why you chose to bracket the read, but you should recognize what is happening from the example above.

There is already a good answer. This is just an example of how you might look at the problem. Also, I would recommend getting what you want to work with just a single file. After that is working, import glob and work on using your mini-solution in the bigger problem.