# Getting csv.Sniffer to work with quoted values

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to use [python's CSV sniffer tool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Sniffer) as suggested in many StackOverflow answers to guess if a given CSV file is delimited by `;` or `,`.

It's working fine with basic files, but when a value contains a delimiter, it is surrounded by double quotes (as the standard goes), and the sniffer throws `_csv.Error: Could not determine delimiter`.

Has anyone experienced that before?

Here is a minimal failing CSV file:

```
column1,column2
0,"a, b"
```

And the proof of concept:

```
Python 3.5.1 (default, Dec  7 2015, 12:58:09) 
[GCC 5.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import csv
>>> f = open("example.csv", "r")
>>> f.seek(0);
0
>>> csv.Sniffer().sniff(f.read(), delimiters=';,')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/csv.py", line 186, in sniff
    raise Error("Could not determine delimiter")
_csv.Error: Could not determine delimiter
```

I have total control over the generation of input CSV file; but sometimes it is modified by a third party using MS Office and the delimiter is replaced by semicolumns, so I have to use this guessing approach.
I know I could stop using commas in the input file, but I would like to know if I'm doing something wrong first.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You are giving the sniffer too much input. Your sample file does work if you run:

```
csv.Sniffer().sniff(f.readline())
```

which uses only the header row to determine the delimiter character. If you want to understand why the Sniffer heuristics fail for more data, there is no substitute for [reading the csv.py library source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/csv.py#L165).

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing like you suggested. That's sad that that's the only way though.

Comment: Thank you!! This seems like a major deficiency of the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Sniffer) which shows the problematic method of reading 1024 bytes: `dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(1024))`. CSV files are always text files with multiple lines, so it seems that `f.readline()` is the right option.

Comment: @msw the link to the CSV source, line 165 now points to an empty line. Not sure if you meant to point to a specific part of the source or not, but if you did it would be a good idea to link to a specific commit for a stable line linking.

Comment: @benregn: The link to the CSV source, line 165, works and makes sense to me — it points to the first line of the `Sniffer` class definition.

Comment: @martineau that's the problem with just linking to `master`, the source can shift. Now line 165 is back to pointing to `class Sniffer:` but didn't when I visited it back in Nov '18.

Comment: I was skimming some file in a google API, and they loaded 1024 lines for the sniffer. I just assumed that was okay. I was wrong. Maybe they had some special reason for wanting to sniff such a large sample, but this answer saved me a lot of troubleshooting

Comment: @msw can you explain why it faIls for more data?