# Performing a calculation on two string rows in a file in Python

Tags: python, integer, rows

I have a csv file with string items in each file. (although some are integer inputs). I wish to subtract row[3] from row[5], but can't quite figure out the syntax to do so. Can anyone help?

```
print("PRINT RECORD" + '\t'+ row[0]+ '\t' + int(row[5])-int(row[3]))
```

The error message is:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Target Stock'
```

I've tried a number of different things which don't work

UPDATE

```
ID NO.     Description       Price  Current Stock   Re Order    Target Stock
12345670    x                  500            2         3          5
12121212    y                  900            1         3          5
```

I need the statement to subtract (in this example): 5-2  and then 5-1

UPDATE:

I tried

```
while row[5] and row[3] != str:
                    print("LOW STOCK" + '\t'+ row[0]+ '\t' + (int(row[5])-int(row[3])))
```

Still, the same error.

**UPDATE**
I've added the header search...but the following error

```
 l=str(row[4])
        for row in reader:
            if(row[3])< (row[4]):
                has_header = csv.Sniffer().has_header(inf.read(1024))
                if has_header:
                    next(incsv)  # skip header row
                    lowstock="true"
                    targetstock_r= int((row[5]))
                    currentstock_r=int((row[3]))
                    reorderstock_r=int((row[4]))
                    writer.writerow(("LOWSTOCK", row[0],(targetstock)-(row[3])))
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
NameError: name 'inf' is not defined
```

Comment: That row item contains `'Target Stock'`, that can't be *casted* to an integer. You may want to review your csv file

Comment: check the values in the respective coloumns as it clearly tells u that it can't cast an string into the integers

Comment: 'Target Stock' is only the header...the rest of the elements under that heading contain only integers

Comment: @pythoncarrot Then skip the header

Comment: something like a while loop? Again, syntax I'm not entirely sure of. while file_to_read != " ":  ?

Comment: See [When processing CSV data, how do I ignore the first line of data?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11349333/1314743) or [Skip the headers when editing a csv file using Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14257373/1314743). That was not really hard to find by searching for "python CSV skip header".

Comment: Can you show some more code?  How are you reading in the file?