# Apply function to URL and write in new column in CSV

Tags: python, csv, for-loop

I'm a newbie and surprised there's already not a clear answer similar to what I'm asking, apologies if this is a duplicate.

I have a list of URLs in a CSV file I'm trying to shorten, I want to loop through my CSV file and then write a new column with the shortened URL right next to the original URL.

```
from pyshorteners import Shortener
import csv

def generate_short(url):
    x = shortener.short(url)
    return x
with open('Links_Test.csv') as csvfile:
    my_date = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect = 'excel')
    for row in my_data: 
        x = shortener.short(row)
        print(X)
```

EDIT:
I keep getting the error "ValueError: Please enter a valid url" and don't know how to proceed from here.....I'm sure I'm the problem.

Here's what my input data looks like:

```
URL
http://www.google.com
http://www.facebook.com
http://www.twitter.com
http://www.linkedin.com
```

and here's what I want my output to look like:

```
URL                        Short_URL
http://www.google.com      http://goo.gle
http://www.facebook.com    http://goo.g3c
http://www.twitter.com     http://goo.g3a
http://www.linkedin.com    http://goo.g2q
```

Thank you for your help.  I was very surprised there's not already a clear answer posted (at least I couldn't find it) so I'm sorry if this is a duplicate.

Comment: The `row` is a list, with a value for every column. If your file has only 1 column, it's a 1-element list, `row[0]` being the url.

Comment: @9000, thanks for the tip, I updated my code but still having problems.

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show `print(row)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the function on `row[0]` or `row['URL']`
Also you have to apply it on `my_data.iterrows()`and not on `my_data`

```
from pyshorteners import Shortener
import pandas as pd

def generate_short(url):
    x = shortener.short(url)
    return x
    my_date = pd.read_csv( 'Link-Tests.csv', sep = "\t") #seperator argument is optional. It can be a semi colon, a tab. Check your CSV file for knowing what the separator is.
    for index,row in my_data.iterrows(): 
        x = shortener.short(row[0])
        print(X)
```

If you can always store the shortened URL into a separate list, convert it into a DataFrame and then merge with the original dataframe based on index.

```
lst = []
my_date = pd.read_csv( 'Link-Tests.csv', sep = "\t")
    for index,row in my_data.iterrows(): 
        x = shortener.short(row[0])
        lst.append(X)
df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=["Short-Url"])  
my_data = my_data.join(df, how= 'outer')
```

Comment: I tried your code and changed 'my_date' to 'my_data', but keep getting the error: " AttributeError: '_csv.reader' object has no attributre 'iterrows' " - perhaps I'm doing something wrong?  I like the idea of joining it back up in Pandas where I can write to CSV.  Is important that I keep the original order for this.  Thank you, Me

Comment: @SDS you made another mistake. Instead of csv_reader use pd.read_csv(file_name)

Comment: @SDS you can now check the latest edit to the answer. Alternatively you can use `pd.read_excel` instead of `pd.read_csv`

Answer (score 0):

First try doing this:

```
from pyshorteners import Shortener
import csv

def generate_short(url):
    x = shortener.short(url)
    return x
with open('Links_Test.csv') as csvfile:
    my_data = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect = 'excel')
    for row in my_data: 
        print(row) # output: ['URL'], ['google.com']...
```

You probably want to use [next()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) or maybe look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349333/when-processing-csv-data-how-do-i-ignore-the-first-line-of-data)  to ignore the header. Also, you probably want to use `row[0]` to get the first item in the list. So your final code might be

```
from pyshorteners import Shortener
import csv

def generate_short(url):
    x = shortener.short(url)
    return x
with open('Links_Test.csv') as csvfile:
    next(csvfile) # skip the header row
    my_data = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect = 'excel')
    for row in my_data: 
        print(row[0]) # output: 'google.com' ....
        # do the link shortener stuff here
```