# Assigning variables from a csv data and skipping couple of lines

Tags: python, csv

Can anyone help me out, I am new to python and I have some problems assigning variables and skipping some lines

My code looks like this:

```
import csv

with open('sample.csv', "r") as csvfile: 

    # Set up CSV reader and process the header
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ') 
    skip_lines = csvfile.readlines()[4:] #skip the first four lines

    capacity = []
    voltage = []
    temperature = []
    impedance = []


# Loop through the lines in the file and get each coordinate
    for row in reader:

        capacity.append(row[0])

        voltage.append(row[1])

        temperature.append(row[2])

        impedance.append(row[3])

        print(capacity, voltage, temperature, impedance)
```

Comment: I noticed you wrote "for row in reader", which doesn't skip the first 4 lines.. but also - what is the question? you didn't specify the problem you're having with the code...

Comment: ```skip_lines = csvfile.readlines()[4:] #skip the first four lines``` this consumes your file pointer in full, you basically have to skip by `next(reader)` as in <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349333/when-processing-csv-data-how-do-i-ignore-the-first-line-of-data>

Comment: The main question I'm asking is how do I assign variables to the csv column  and ignore the first 4 lines because they are not part of the dataset

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
skip_lines = csvfile.readlines()[4:]
```

This reads the *entire file* into memory, and puts everything but the first 4 lines in `skip_lines`. By the time you get to:

```
for row in reader:
```

The file-handler is exhausted.

To skip a single line in the file-handler, use:

```
next(csvfile)
```

Since you want to skip the first four:

```
for _ in range(4):
    next(csvfile)
```