# Sorting csv file with over 171 columns, but some rows have fewer of them?

Tags: python, csv, sorting

I have a CSV file of 1 GB with around 1 million records, each row is 171 columns, I did some research and came up with this code. I have reduced the size of file to 5 MB for testing purposes, but there are still 171 columns. The code works fine as long as the sorting column index is below 50. Even on 49 it works fine, but I have columns with index 151, 153. I want to sort the file with those columns.

**Error:**

When I give it index 50 or above it throws the error:

```
  data.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(*sort_key_columns))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

**My Code:**

```
def sort_csv(csv_filename, sort_key_columns):
    data = []
    with open(csv_filename, 'r') as f:
        for row in csv.reader(f):
            data.append(row)
    data.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(*sort_key_columns))
    with open(csv_filename, 'w', newline='') as f:
        csv.writer(f).writerows(data)

sort_csv('Huge_Complete_B2B_file_1_1.csv', [49])
```

Comment: that's probably because there are some rows with less than 51 columns. Could you check that for instance by computing the minimum number of columns?

Comment: well the column obviously there but the data is missing in alot of columns for sure

Comment: obviously some columns are missing... Can you do `print(min(len(row) for row in csv.reader(f)))` just after opening the file (instead of the for loop)

Comment: note: your loop would be much better like: `data = list(csv.reader(f))`

Comment: the printed result is 50

Comment: I don't understand what does it mean ? and can i fix it

Comment: yeah, it means that some row has only 50 cols, as I expected. So your input data is kind of corrupt. You can print this row in your loop (test the length `if len(row)==50: print(row)`) to debug

Comment: its only shows one row

Comment: yeah, that's the one you have issues with. Only you know if this is expected or not.

Comment: OK, so in this case i will remove that line or fix, is there anything more permanent you suggest because i have hundreds of other file, i cannot manually change lines of each file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the short row by writing your own version of `operator.itemgetter` which you can base on the code equivalent to it which is shown in its [online documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter).

The custom version below simply supplies a specified value for any that are missing. This will cause the row to be sorted as though it had that value in it at that indexed position.

**Note:** That this assumes all the missing items should use the same default `MISSING` value. If that's not the case, it could be enhanced to allow a different one to be specified for each index in the sequence of them passed to it. This would likely require an additional argument.

```
import csv
import operator

def my_itemgetter(*indexes, MISSING=''):
    if len(indexes) == 1:
        index = indexes[0]
        def getter(obj):
            try:
                return obj[index]
            except IndexError:
                return MISSING
    else:
        def getter(obj):
            try:
                return tuple(obj[index] for index in indexes)
            except IndexError:
                return tuple(obj[index] if index < len(obj) else MISSING
                                for index in indexes)
    return getter

def sort_csv(csv_filename, sort_key_columns):
    with open(csv_filename, 'r', newline='') as f:
        data = [row for row in csv.reader(f)]

    data.sort(key=my_itemgetter(*sort_key_columns))

    with open(csv_filename, 'w', newline='') as f:
        csv.writer(f).writerows(data)

sort_csv('Huge_Complete_B2B_file_1_1.csv', [0, 171])
```

Comment: Working great !!! Its sorting with both columns index now. Is there any way i can avoid reading the first row within this same code ?

Comment: To skip the first row, just put a `next(f)` immediately _before_ the `data = [row for...` line. **Note** this will also effectively remove the header in the output file. Also see [_When processing CSV data, how do I ignore the first line of data?_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349333/when-processing-csv-data-how-do-i-ignore-the-first-line-of-data).

Comment: P.S. You can preserve the first header row by using `header = next(f)` and then output it manually when overwriting the file at the end with a `f.write(header)` before the `writerows()` call.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that one of your files contains a truncated row below 51 columns.

If you don't care about your input being corrupt, you could filter it out while reading the input & sort it, in one line:

```
def sort_csv(csv_filename, sort_key_columns):
    with open(csv_filename, 'r') as f:
        data = sorted([row for row in csv.reader(f) if len(row)>=171],key=operator.itemgetter(*sort_key_columns))
    # then write the file
```

Comment: Thankyou so very much!!! It worked
2 questions: (1) when i give it two columns why does it only sort with the first one. (2) how can i avoid first line from sorting

Comment: like [155, 156] it only does the 155 part