# how to correctly handle csv.reader headers

Tags: python, csv

When reading csv files, sometimes the first row (or more than one) are headers that we don't want to include in our data.

If I don't need the data from the headers I just use `next` before declaring the reader (if more than one row is used for headers I can call next multiple times):

```
with open('myfile.csv', 'rb') as f:
    next(f)                         #skip first row
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        #process my data
```

Sometimes however I don't want to include the headers in my data but still need their values. In that case I transform the `csv.reader` into a list and handle the headers separately.

```
with open('myfile.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = list(csv.reader(f))

    my_header = reader.pop(0)   #remove header

    for row in reader:
        #process my data
```

This works and I'm happy about it. But I'm not sure if it's the "best practice" way of using `csv.reader` and there are other ways worth exploring.

Comment: look at [`pandas.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), which is a very powerful and versatile reader.

Comment: This is a recipe for opinionated comments and answers. But you don't need to convert the `reader` into a `list`. `my_header = next(reader)` should get the header row if you need it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When processing CSV data, how do I ignore the first line of data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349333/when-processing-csv-data-how-do-i-ignore-the-first-line-of-data)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's indeed not the best practice - it reads the whole file in memory for no good reason.  The funny part is that there's almost nothing to change to your first snippet to get the headers...

`next(iterator)` *does* return the "current" element:

```
>>> it = iter(["hello", "world"])
>>> next(it)
'hello'
>>> next(it)
'world'
>>> next(it)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

So all you have to do is

```
with open('myfile.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    headers = next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        #process my data
```

FWIW, the way you skip "the first row" in your first snippet is brittle - you're actually skipping the first *line*, which is not necessarily the first *row* (some csv format have newlines embeded in rows), so for the "no header" version you actually want:

```
with open('myfile.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader) # skip first row
    for row in reader:
        #process my data
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to use your csv file organized with a header line and then the values: csv + DictReader
ex:

```
with open ('myfile.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
csv_reader = csv.DictReader (csv_file)
     for row in csv_reader:
         print (row.get ('column1')) # print the value of column1 without title
```

With this method, you can ignore your header line and precisely target the data you need, and your code will be cleaner.
Give me a return, see you later.

Comment: But sometimes I don't want to ignore the header, just process it separately from the rest of the data.