# Skip Header Row when reading in a CSV

Tags: python-3.x, mapreduce

I'm trying to read in a csv file from the command line and do a few calculations on the columns. However, I'm struggling to skip the first row (Header Row) when the file gets read in.

For example, here is a screenshot of the csv file:
[image]

Here is the code I'm using currently:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import re
import csv

def main(argv):
    for row in csv.reader(iter(sys.stdin.readline, "")):
        quantity = int(row[3])
        price_per_unit = int(row[5])
        cum_sum = quantity*price_per_unit
        print(row[0]+" "+str(cum_sum)+" "+row[6]+"\t"+"1")

#Note there are two underscores around name and main
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

From the command line I'm running this:

```
python problem1.py < orders.csv
```

Comment: why not use pandas framework to read csv? it is very convenient to do such work

Comment: Ultimately this code is going to be used in Hadoop Mapreduce, but I'm trying to make sure it works in python first. I'm also unsure that pandas is available in MapReduce at this time.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349333/when-processing-csv-data-how-do-i-ignore-the-first-line-of-data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When processing CSV data, how do I ignore the first line of data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349333/when-processing-csv-data-how-do-i-ignore-the-first-line-of-data)

Comment: It's almost a meme how people constantly import the whole of Pandas, incorporating an additional dependency, @AtulShanbhag, just to read a simple CSV file, when the `csv` module is built in. Why not use the `csv` built-in for the purpose it was designed for? Because you don't know how? Is that the reason? Keep it simple and lean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do one iteration before you start the loop. This is fairly common.

```
my_iterator = iter(sys.stdin.readline, "")
next(my_iterator)  # Gets the first line and does nothing with it.
for row in csv.reader(my_iterator):
    quantity = int(row[3])
```

Comment: An iterator object has no `next()` method. Use the built-in function `next()` instead.

Comment: @blhsing how would that look in this case?

Comment: `next(my_iterator)` instead of `my_iterator.next()`.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I googled it and confused myself. Dunder next would also work