# How to read CSV file specified column without using pandas?

Tags: python

```
def loadData(fileName):
    x = []
    y = []
    fl = csv.reader(open(fileName,'r'))
    x = list(fl)
    y.append([row[13] for row in fl])
    return x, y
```

I use this but got y is empty, my csv data is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9qQK.png)

I want got x is all the rows, and y output [19.2, 20.8]

Comment: The CSV data shoud be:
0.15098,0,10.01,0,0.547,6.021,82.6,2.7474,6,432,17.8,394.51,10.3,19.2
12.048,0,18.1,0,0.614,5.648,87.6,1.9512,24,666,20.2,291.55,14.1,20.8

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11350095/355230) to a different CSV-related question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over the rows in csv file, as you did for y: `x.append()`

The complete code should look something like this:

```
def loadData(fileName):
    x = []
    y = []
    fl = csv.reader(open(fileName,'r'))
    for row in fl:
        y.append([row[-1:])
        x.append([row[:-1])
    return x, y
```

This gives you a list of lists for x. I am not sure what you expect the output to look like however if you just want a flat list you can use a flatten lambda function (source see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)):

```
flatten = lambda l: [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
x = flatten(x)
```

Please note that its recommend to use `with`-Syntax for file readers
An Example for the CSV Reader from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html):

```
with open('eggs.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
...     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
...     for row in spamreader:
...         print(', '.join(row))
```

Comment: The output of y is still empty in this way, the x is correct.

Comment: I found an interesting thing, if I delete x.append([row[:13] for row in fl]), the output y is correct

Comment: Thank you, btw can I format the output to two brackets rather than three? I would like to get [['19.2']], [['20.8']] but now it is [[['19.2']], [['20.8']]]