# Downloading Image from CSV file

Tags: python-3.x, image, image-processing, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to download all the images in a CSV file to my computer. Unfortunately, it seems that because the first row contains a header instead of a link, it doesn't work. Could you please help me fix my mistake?
   import csv
    import requests

```
with open('abc.csv') as csvfile:
    csvrows = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for row in csvrows:
        filename = row[1]
        url = row[2]
        print(url)
        result = requests.get(url, stream=True)
        if result.status_code == 200:
            image = result.raw.read()
            open(filename,"wb").write(image)
```

Below is my abc.csv file:

```
    identifier                             link           likes_count   company
0   2292512316069378197 https://www.instagram.com/p/B_Qo84ihfiV 9608    Nike
1   2292462538514040606 https://www.instagram.com/p/B_QdohlBQce 9462    Nike
2   2292418655784545069 https://www.instagram.com/p/B_QTp8mhCst 22033   Nike
3   2292372137723669561 https://www.instagram.com/p/B_QJFBSBaw5 14112   Nike
4   2292334760619881771 https://www.instagram.com/p/B_QAlHJBzUr 5974    Nike
```

... ... ... ... ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to ignore the first line of data when processing CSV data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349333/how-to-ignore-the-first-line-of-data-when-processing-csv-data)

Comment: Your delimiter appears to be a space rather than a comma...

Comment: @MarkSetchell if I change the delimiter to be a space, I get the error:
 "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: @ruhaib it could be, but i am still trying to adapt that code and so far have not succeeded..

Comment: Are you on Windows by any chance?

Comment: yes I am @MarkSetchell

Comment: Did you try `TYPE abc.csv` to see what's really in your file?

Comment: Do you mean: type(abc)? pandas.core.frame.DataFrame. 'TYPE abc.csv' returns an error

Comment: `TYPE` is a Windows `CMD.EXE` command that you run in a Command Prompt (DOSbox).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212288/discussion-between-tony-flager-and-mark-setchell).